# Sql Server date type appears as text field in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, date, ms-access

I have a MS Access 2010 front end / SQL Server 2012 back end database, with a number of date fields in different tables. Sometimes I need to store the time, so I have used data types datetime or smalldatetime. However certain fields only need to store the date, so I used data type Date.

My problem is that in MS Access, my ODBC-linked table shows the Date data type fields as Text. This is then leading to problems with some dates being stored in the yyyy-dd-mm format and others in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Is this a bug? Do I need to use smalldatetime?

Thanks for any assistance,
Jim

Comment: Just to clarify this a display formatting issue since SQL server stores a Date as a [3 byte integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). The format of the date isn't stored.

Comment: Hi Conrad, it is a formatting issue, but it goes beyond that. For example, I have an access query which should exclude any record where [datefield] > Date(), but because [datefield] is being loaded as a text string, the record gets included whatever.

Also, if I look at the table design of the linked table in Access, it shows the field as a text field, not a date one.

Comment: You might want to try `CDate([datefield]) > Date()`  or try using a `DateTime` instead of a `Date` and use an input mask.

Comment: Thanks Conrad, I have gone to using DateTime

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue myself linking Access 2007 and SQL Server 2008.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383947/date-conversion-issue-ms-access-to-sql-server), if you look at Albert D. Kallal's comment to the first answer, it tells us that the problem is with an outdated driver connecting the front end to the back end.

If you aren't able to choose an up-to-date driver (and bear in mind that even if you can, other users of your database on different client machines may not be able to) the workaround is to use datetime data type in every case.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I suspected, that it was a driver issue. Rather than mess around with new drivers (which the client may not have on production machines) I have changed everything to datetime. Just seems a bit of a rubbish solution to a problem which should not exist.

P.S. I tried to rate your answer, but apparently I dont have sufficient feedback!

Comment: @BiigJiim: you don't need to upvote the answer, just mark as "the" answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expound on the comment given by @BiigJiim I actually had the Native client 11.0 driver already installed but as I was creating DSN-Less table connections I had to change my connection string formally to: `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};`

Also as an additional note, I do not believe the Date and DateTime2 data types are recommended for Microsoft Access integration. If memory serves me correctly it recommends either DateTime and SmallDateTime. I get not needing the Time in a lot of circumstances, but you can easily format it via the front end... especially within Access.

Comment: I know this is old @Anthony Griggs , but this is spot-on.  I also am using DNS-Less table connections, I updated the string to `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};` and hey presto the `date` fields stopped being strings and became dates again.  A very big thank you!!!