# Best way to handle time formats from SQL Server in Access front end

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I've migrated a database formerly in Access to SQL Server and am now rebuilding my Access front end to work with that SQL Server back end using a DSN-less link. I'm running into issues with new data entry in my time field. The error I get is `ODBC--update on a linked table...failed. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (#0)`. I'm assuming this has to do with the way Access converts the data into short text from SQL Server, where it is a time(0) data type.

My question is what is the best way to handle "time" data to work in both Access and SQL Server? Ideally users would enter data in Access simply as something like "0130" where this means "1 hour and 30 minutes" (we never record seconds). And ideally the data in SQL Server would be formatted in some sort of time or datetime/datetime2 format.

I'm in a position to modify the formatting or code of the Access front end or the SQL Server back end (or both)--what's the cleanest way to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server date type appears as text field in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299222/sql-server-date-type-appears-as-text-field-in-ms-access)

Comment: After a migration to SQL server there should be ZERO  changes to your date/time code, and ZERO changes to your forms, and SQL, and even zero changes to VBA code that works with date/time data. If you have to make changes, then you likely migrated the columns to datetime2 and not datetime. If you used datetime2 on sql server, then you must use the newer native 11 (or later) drivers that you have to install  on each workstation. Or use the long time build in SQL driver, and use datetime data types. Any any access linked table in desing mode - check for date/time columns being seen as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to user data type *DateTime* in SQL Server. Any ODBC driver will read and write that from Access as native DateTime of VBA.

If you must use *DateTime2* in SQL Server, you must install and use one of the never ODBC drivers, not the "SQL Server" ODBC driver that comes with Windows as it cannot read the microsecond resolution of DateTime2.

You should never use the other date/time data types of SQL Server: Time and Short Date